# Buggy transfer of single long long numbers to int array

Tags: arrays, c, modulo, long-long

I’m trying to grab a Long Long Int and split each place number into it’s own spot in an array, in order of course, with array[0] being the largest number.

So for instance, if the number was 314, then array[0] = 3, array[1] =1, and array[2] = 4.

This is part of a calculator project for a microcontroller where I’m writing the graphics library (for fun) and using arrays to display each line.

The issue is, it needs to be able to deal with really large numbers (9,999,999,999+), and I’m having dramas with the large stuff. If the Long Long is < 1,000,000, it will writes all the numbers perfectly, but the more numbers I add, they all start to be written wrong towards the end.

For instance, 1,234,567,890 displays as 1,234,567,966.

Here’s the snippet of code I’m using:

```
long long int number = 1234567890;
int answerArray[10];
int numberLength = 10;

for(writeNumber = 0; writeNumber < numberLength; writeNumber++)
{
    answerArray[writeNumber] = ((int)(number / pow(10, (numberLength - 1 - writeNumber))) % 10;
}
```

I’m fairly sure this has to do with either the “%” and multiple data types, because any number within the Int range works perfectly.

Can you see where I’m going wrong? Is there a better way achieve my goal? Any tips for large numbers?

Comment: `pow` is for floating point exponentiation; it will lose precision with `long long` arguments, and floating point is not something you want to use on a microcontroller.  Typically you would rewrite this to successively divide and mod by 10 instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge amazing i didn’t know that, so you think just do it 10 at a time?

Comment: Yes, it's easier if you fill the array from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're casting what is potentially a very large number to an `int`.  Look at the iteration when `writeNumber` is `numberLength-1`.  In that case, you're dividing a `long long` by 1 and then forcing the result into an `int`.  Once `number` becomes larger than 2^31-1, you're going to run into problems.

You should remove the cast altogether as well as the call to `pow`.  Instead, you should iteratively grab the next digit by modding out by 10 and then dividing `number` (or a copy of it) by 10.

E.g.,

```
int index = sizeof(answerArray)/sizeof(answerArray[0]);
for (long long x=number; x>0; x /= 10) {
    answerArray[--index] = x%10;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(answerArray)` should be the number of elements, `sizeof answerArray / sizeof *answerArray`.

Comment: Thank you! And modding a long long int will still work fine because it’s a whole number?

Comment: It will indeed.

Comment: As long as it is non-negative. For negative operands, `%` can produce negative results.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `pow` is

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

When you call the function, the computation will implicitly use floating point. That is why it is no longer exact as pure integer operations.

In addition, you have to be careful how you cast to `int`.

In your question, you have

```
((int)(number / pow(10, (numberLength - 1 - writeNumber))) % 10;
```

The parentheses do not match, so I will assume you meant:

```
(int)(number / pow(10, (numberLength - 1 - writeNumber))) % 10;
```

However, here you cast a number that may exceed the range of `int` before you apply the modulo 10 operation. That can result in an integer overflow. The code is doing the same as if you had written:

```
((int)(number / pow(10, (numberLength - 1 - writeNumber)))) % 10;
```

To avoid the overflow, it would be better to perform the modulo operation first. However, you are dealing implicitly with double at this point (because of pow), so it is not ideal either. It is best to stick with pure integer operations to avoid these pitfalls.